# Как сделать чтобы при ширине экрана меньше 1140 блоки шли в столбик?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать чтобы при ширине экрана меньше 1140 блоки шли в столбик?

В чём проблема? Объясню: у меня есть `container` в котором есть `col-4`. В `col-4` блоки идут в ряд. Это нормально для большого экрана. А если просматривать на телефоне, то должно быть в столбик. Но так не получаеться сделать.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Марко Мідик портфолио</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
     @font-face{
      font-family: Font;
      src:url(fonts/AA-Higherup.ttf);
     }
    
     .maintext{
      font-size:100px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      font-family: Font;
     }
     .text{
      font-size:50px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      font-family: Font;
     }
     .arrow{
      width:10px;
      height:10px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50px;
      left: 50%;
    
     }
     .title{
      font-family: Font;
      font-size:50px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%
     }
    .header{
            background: red;
            background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/lMCRt5S.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;     
            height: 100vh;
            color:white;
            text-align: center;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    .container{
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 75px;
        }
        .row {
          display: flex;
        }
        
        .col-4{
            width: 50%;
            margin:0;
            float: left ;
        }
        .portfoliotext{
            font-family: Font;
            font-size:25px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .portfolioimg{
         text-align: center;
        }
        .text1{
            font-size:50px;
            margin:0;
            font-family: Font;
            color:white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .links{
            font-size:50px;
            color:white;
        }
        .links:hover{
            color:black;
        }
        .bottom{
            background-color: #450f55;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20vh;
        }
        img{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        @media (max-width: 1160px){
             .container{
              width: 100%;
             }
             .col-4{
              width:100%;
              margin: 0;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
              padding-left: 15px;
              padding-right: 15px;
              text-align: center;
             }
            }
    </style>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
       $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#arrowdown").click(function (){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#scroll").offset().top
                    }, 2000);
                });
            });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <!-----
     HEADER
     ----->
    <div class="header">
     <div class="maintext">Марко Мідик</div>
     <div class="text">Разработка сайтов на языке<br>HTML и CSS</div>
     <div class="arrow"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OGfL0Qf.png" width="75" height="50" id="arrowdown"></div>
    </div>
     <!-----
     PORTFOLIO
     ----->
     <div class="title">Портфолио</div>
    <div class="portfolio">
              <div class="container" id="scroll">
               <div class="row">
               <div class="col-4">
                <div class="portfolioimg"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bkpKc0u.jpg" alt="Сайт-портфолио"></div>
                <div class="portfoliotext">Сайт на котором вы находитесь</div>
               </div>
               <!---
                --->
                <div class="col-4">
              <div class="portfolioimg1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2coBS2k.jpg" alt="Журнал о программировании"></div>
                <div class="portfoliotext">Сайт в разработке</div>
               </div>
            
              </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            
             <!-----
             BOTTOM
             ----->
            <div class="bottom">
               <div class="container" id="scroll">
               <div class="row">
               <div class="col-4">
                <div class="text2"><p class="text1">Связь со мной</p></div>
               </div>
               <!---
                --->
                <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="links"><center><a href="https://www.instagram.com/midykmarko/" class="links"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                   <a href="https://vk.com/midykmarko" class="links"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></center></div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут конечно надо полностью весь код переписывать:) Но немного поэкспериментировав с вашим кодом, удалось достичь нужного результата.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Марко Мідик портфолио</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        @font-face{
            font-family: Font;
            src:url(fonts/AA-Higherup.ttf);
        }
    
        .maintext{
            font-size:100px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            font-family: Font;
        }
        .text{
            font-size:50px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-family: Font;
        }
        .arrow{
            width:10px;
            height:10px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50px;
            left: 50%;
    
        }
        .title{
            font-family: Font;
            font-size:50px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%
        }
    .header{
            background: red;
            background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/lMCRt5S.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;     
            height: 100vh;
            color:white;
            text-align: center;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    .container{
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 75px;
        }
        .row {
          display: flex;
        }
        
        .col-4{
            width: 50%;
            margin:0;
            float: left ;
        }
        .portfoliotext{
            font-family: Font;
            font-size:25px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .portfolioimg{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .text1{
            font-size:50px;
            margin:0;
            font-family: Font;
            color:white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .links{
            font-size:50px;
            color:white;
        }
        .links:hover{
            color:black;
        }
        .bottom{
            background-color: #450f55;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20vh;
        }
        img{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        @media (max-width: 1140px){

                .title{
                    position: relative;
                    left: 0;
                    text-align: center; 
                }
                .portfolio .row{
                    flex-direction: column;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .portfolio .col-4{
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .portfolioimg, .portfolioimg1{
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }
    </style>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#arrowdown").click(function (){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#scroll").offset().top
                    }, 2000);
                });
            });
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-----
        HEADER
        ----->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="maintext">Марко Мідик</div>
        <div class="text">Разработка сайтов на языке<br>HTML и CSS</div>
        <div class="arrow"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OGfL0Qf.png" width="75" height="50" id="arrowdown"></div>
    </div>
        <!-----
        PORTFOLIO
        ----->
        <div class="title">Портфолио</div>
    <div class="portfolio">
                    <div class="container" id="scroll">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="portfolioimg"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bkpKc0u.jpg" alt="Сайт-портфолио"></div>
                            <div class="portfoliotext">Сайт на котором вы находитесь</div>
                        </div>
                        <!---
                            --->
                            <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="portfolioimg1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2coBS2k.jpg" alt="Журнал о программировании"></div>
                            <div class="portfoliotext">Сайт в разработке</div>
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <!-----
                BOTTOM
                ----->
            <div class="bottom">
                        <div class="container" id="scroll">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="text2"><p class="text1">Связь со мной</p></div>
                        </div>
                        <!---
                            --->
                            <div class="col-4">
                              <div class="links"><center><a href="https://www.instagram.com/midykmarko/" class="links"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                                <a href="https://vk.com/midykmarko" class="links"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></center></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Если вас ответ устраивает, отметьте его,как правильный :)